# oracle web logic server is not installed an error comes while files are extracting

Tags: oracle, server, weblogic

[I'm trying to install oracle weblogic server on window 10. But files does not extract. jar file does not execute. the error can be seen from screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UJmb.png)

Comment: [Please post text rather than images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). This is off-topic for this site anyway though. You also haven't said what the log said was actually wrong.

Comment: the error is :
Launcher log file is C:\Users\QAMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2018-08-02_05-20-59PM\launcher2018-08-02_05-20-59PM.log.
Extracting files........Self extraction to C:\Users\QAMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl5447954627865190240.tmp failed.

Comment: The log file text is :
 com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Launcher log file is C:\Users\QAMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2018-08-02_05-20-59PM\launcher2018-08-02_05-20-59PM.log.
 com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Extracting to C:\Users\QAMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl5447954627865190240.tmp.
 com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Extracting files...
 com.oracle.cie.nextgen.launcher.LogUtils - Self extraction to C:\Users\QAMAR\AppData\Local\Temp\orcl5447954627865190240.tmp failed.